# Xamarin - Binding to call a function

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, pull-to-refresh

I'm using a nuget package called `Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh`.

So my `MainPage.Xaml` Has:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TheOctant"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;assembly=Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh"
         x:Class="TheOctant.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <ScrollView>
        <controls:PullToRefreshLayout x:Name="ptrl" RefreshCommand="{Binding UponRefresh}" RefreshColor="Blue">
            <local:ZoomWebView x:Name="webview" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></local:ZoomWebView>
        </controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

So look at `RefreshCommand="{Binding UponRefresh}"`, I'm trying to bind it to a c# function in `MainPage.Xaml.cs`

So Here's my failed attempt in `MainPage.Xaml.cs`:

```
namespace TheOctant
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void UponRefresh()
    {
        webview.Source = "http://www.google.com";
    }
}
}
```

But it doesn't work. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: The namespace in your XAML is `TheOctant.MainPage` but your `MainPage` is in `PullToRefreshTest`'s namespace, maybe that is the issue?

Comment: @RonBeyer haha i changed that to PullToRefreshTest because I didn't want anyone to see it HAHA. oops e_e But it is actually the same namespace

Answer (score 0):

No. As the name implies, `RefreshCommand` needs to be a `Command`

```
public ICommand UponRefresh
{
    get {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            webview.Source = "http://www.google.com";
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh okay. So I just add this in my MainPage.Xaml.cs and I'm good to go?

Comment: It works but now i'm getting a spinner that goes on forever. any ideas?

Comment: read the docs: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout#api - there is a IsRefreshing property that you need to bind or set manually

Comment: Yup i have, but i'm not sure how to set that isrefreshing thing